# Multiple JQuery Events; would like to use $(this)

Tags: jquery, this, multiple-instances

I have two identical events in the same document, but only one works, the other is inactive. This code shows the same ID, which was a silly oversight, I have used different IDs, to no avail.

How can I use $(this) to affect both events?

Here is my code.

```
<fieldset class="clear">
    <div class="auth_98">
        <legend>Is this a conference?</legend>
        <input class="authradio" type="radio" name="conf" id="confyes" value="yes">
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input class="authradio" type="radio" name="conf" value="no" checked="checked">
        <label>No</label>
        <!-- begin Conference Toggle -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.hideme').hide()
                $('.authradio').change(function() {
                    var $stat = $('#confyes')[0].checked;
                    if ($stat == true) $('.hideme').slideDown();
                    else $('.hideme').slideUp();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!-- end Conference Toggle -->
        <!-- hidden conference section -->
        <div class="hideme">
            <div class="auth_50">
                <legend>Conference Role</legend>
                <input class="authradio" type="radio" name="conference" value="Atendee" checked="checked">
                <label>Attendee</label>
                <input class="authradio" type="radio" name="conference" value="Presenter">
                <label>Presenter</label>
                <input class="authradio" type="radio" name="conference" value="invitedspeaker">
                <label>Invited Speaker</label>
            </div>
            <div class="auth_50">
                <label>
                    <legend>Conference Website</legend>
                </label>
                <input class="authurl" type="url" placeholder="www.amazingsciencestuff.com">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: When you say you have that code twice...do you mean everything is a duplicate, including ID's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have 2 elements with the same id, so if you are trying to apply that code to 2 instances of the same html, the `$('#confyes')` selector will only find the first instance of that id.

You can use a class selector on `.authradio` and then navigate the dom to find the associated `.hideme` div to show. I assume you want something like this

```
$('.authradio').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'yes') 
        $(this).parent().find('.hideme').slideDown();
    else 
        $(this).parent().find('.hideme').slideUp();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AWXMW/2/)

Comment: Thank you.  $(this) did the trick.  I'm not sure I totally get it, but I like $(this).

Comment: $('.authradio') is a class selector, so it will select all elements that have class="authradio". If you have 2 elements that have that class, this code will wire up a function to the change event on each of them. If either is changed, the function will execute, and $(this) refers to the element that was changed. Hopefully that makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code has an input with an id (confyes).  If there is more that one instance of that code then there is more than one instance of that id, which is not allowed.  Each instance needs a unique id.

jQuery selector will always only act on the first instance of an id when using an ID selector such as $('#confyes').  Maybe the first one would be confyes_98, and the second would be confyes_99.  Or maybe you could use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: I made the ID selectors unique, and the result was the second one worked, but the first one would open upon the change - immediately closing again.  It seemed like a solid solution, but something was wonky.  I even tried giving them dissimilar names with a similar wonky-ness.